# ¿Cómo puedo realizar con Django una importación sin que el ID de un modelo se autoincremente 2 veces antes de ser guardado a la BD de Postgresql?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin, autoincremento

Estoy tratando de realizar una importación directamente con el admin de Django, por lo cual he realizado un modelo, el mismo que tiene un identificador que se autoincrementa, el problema de este es que cuando trato de importar una tabla de excel el identificador empieza desde 2.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no solo eso, si no que el identificador se vuelve a incrementar cuando le doy al botón confirma incremento.
Dándome como resultado lo siguiente. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual se esperaba que sea, ID 1,2,3.

A continuación muestro el código utilizado hasta el momento.
Model:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Admin: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No inicia en 1 ya que estas usando un campo auto incremental el cual mantiene el conteo de los objetos creados (aunque los hayas borrado después), el id inicia en el ultimo conteo que lleva, si te inicia en 2 es por que has de haber creado antes un registro con el id 1 y si no te aparece es por que lo borraste.

Suponiendo que usas postgresql y quieres reiniciar la secuencia del campo auto incremental borra los objetos que tienes en la tabla y ejecuta este comando:

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset myapp| psql
```

Donde myapp es el nombre de la aplicación donde tienes el modelo, esto te va a generar un sql y lo va a mandar directamente a psql para reiniciar el conteo.

Si usas otro engine para db ejecuta solo:

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset myapp
```

Esto de va a imprimir el sql que necesitas aplicar en tu base.

Si estas en fase de desarrollo, lo mas sencillo es que borres tu base y la generes de nuevo para que el contador del campo auto incremental inicie en 0.

Puedes leer mas de este comando aqui: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset